# use resourse string value in StringDef/TypeDef android

Tags: android, typedef, android-resources

I have a stringDef/ TypeDef class as follows

```
public class Codes {
      public static final String Code_1 = "Code1";
      public static final String Code_2 = "Code2";
      public static final String Code_3 = "Code3";


      @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE) @StringDef({
            Code_1, Code_2, Code_3 })

      public @interface CodesMessageDef {
      }
}
```

I would like to set values of Code_1,2,3 from R.String.code_1 rather than manually entering.

Is there any way to achieve this usecase.

Thanks in advance.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361/5288316) for how to get application context from a static method. Note that using this to get the context is not a memory leak because you are using an application context.

Now you can do:

```
public static final String Code_1 = MyApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.id.code1);
public static final String Code_2 = MyApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.id.code2);
public static final String Code_3 = MyApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.id.code3);
```

I guess it should work.

Comment: Actually i'm able to get context but the issue is at

 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE) @StringDef({
            Code_1, Code_2, Code_3 }) 

It only accepts constants, but by using resouces the value cant be constant, Is there any possibility to overcome this??

Comment: Just read a bit about that and turns out you can't do that sorry. But why did you want to do it maybe there's another solution?

Comment: I have an text field which only accepts one among these 5 strings provided. Initially i have used ENUM but trying to avoid ENUMS.

Comment: I tried it, but in case of multi language support it wont be applicable